# android: Alarm remian stop between some specific interval

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager, alarm

I am going to set daily alarm in my app.

All works fine in it. But now i want is: for specific time duration, my alarm should remain silent.

e.g: if i have Set the alarm should be play at every 30 minutes and if i have given like it should be remain silent from 1:00 AM to 2:00 AM then it should not be play during that silent period.

I have code for that like this:

Every 30 minutes, my service will call and if the time is remain silent between 1:00 AM to 2:00 AM.

See below code:

```
Calendar currentTime = new GregorianCalendar();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

    Calendar start_time = new GregorianCalendar();
    start_time.set(Calendar.HOUR, sHour);
    start_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
    start_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    start_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    start_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);

    Calendar end_time = new GregorianCalendar();
    end_time.set(Calendar.HOUR, eHour);
    end_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, eMinute);
    end_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    end_time.set(Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DATE);
    end_time.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);




   if((!SILENCE) && (((!(start_time.getTimeInMillis() < currentTime.getTimeInMillis())) && (!(currentTime.getTimeInMillis() < end_time.getTimeInMillis()) )))){
    // Alarm will play
}
else{
// you are in Silent mode
}
```

So please give me solution that while i am not getting it works ?
Here with this code i always ocurs "you are in Silent mode"

So please help me for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing wrong

```
currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR);
```

Using this sentence you are setting the hours and minutes to the integer values.
for example  Calendar.HOUR has constant value 10 like wise all the constant have different fixed values and you are assigning this values to the calendar and probably it causes an issue to you.

**Solution**

If you want to set the only hours and minutes then leave the other fields so that it will automatically consider your current datatime.

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstant();
currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
```

so this will set hours and minutes in the calendar to the values which you provided and it will set other information like day, month, years and others to the current.

**Edit**

If you are facing the issue to get the current time in milli seconds then use `System.currentTimeMillis();`.

And for get future time in milli seconds you have to set appropriate time in the calendar and after that you have to get the time from the calendar in the milli seconds like `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: realy Nice answer. But let me give more idea that if i want to get the current time in miliseconds then ? I mean with your code hours and minuts are the current hour and minute so how to set it in that code ?

Comment: I have set the hour and minute for the start and the Endtime but for current time how to set it ??

Answer (score 1):

try it -

```
if((!SILENCE) && (start_time.getTimeInMillis() > System.getTimeInMillis())){
// Alarm will play
}
else{
// you are in Silent mode
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i also have to check for the End time. As because endtime i want alarm to be play